Interpreting spectrum from waveforms from simple and complex examples
I am reading Jurafsky and Martin's Speech and Language Processing Chapter 28 on Phonetics (pages 15,16) and they introduce waveforms and spectrum.
What I don't understand is how they came from a waveform with 2 frequencies in this image of 10 Hz and 1000 Hz waves

to a spectrum with 2 straight lines.


I understand the position of the 2 frequencies but why are they straight all the way up? Is it because there are different points in the amplitude that repeat themselves at the same frequency?

Similarly, the next waveform is more complicated but the authors write that there are 3 waves with 3 frequencies: 234 Hz, 936 Hz and 1872 Hz.

And they get this corresponding spectrum and they write

Figure 28.18 shows a smoothed spectrum for the waveform in Fig. 28.17, computed with a discrete Fourier transform (DFT).



Why is it that in this case, the spectrum is continuous and not 3 vertical lines?


One only gets "vertical lines" in a spectrum plot (e.g. isolated non-zero values in an FFT) when the signal is exactly integer periodic within the length of the FFT aperture, and the sum of a sparse number of pure sinusoids.
The basis vectors of a DFT are pure sinusoids.  If the signal is an exact match for just 2 basis vectors, that signal will be orthogonal to all other basis vectors.  Thus the FFT result can have only 2 non-zero values (other than microscopic numerical noise from floating point arithmetic "errors").
Most vocal signals will not be purely periodic, so will have sidebands.  Nor will the period of the vocal signal's frequency be an exact fit to the FFT window width.  Plus any non-rectangular windowing of the FFT's input data will also cause various windowing artifacts, such as sidebands plus a non-zero noise floor.

Long time no see hotpaw! good to see you


I understand the position of the 2 frequencies but why are they straight all the way up? Is it because there are different points in the amplitude that repeat themselves at the same frequency?

That's a plotting software decision. It artificially connects data points. In this case the data points are $\{...,...,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,...,...\}$ (I estimated the spike to reach $100 \,\texttt{dB/Hz}$)

Why is it that in this case, the spectrum is continuous and not 3 vertical lines?

The authors tell you why:
Thus, Fig. 28.18 shows significant frequency components at around 930 Hz, 1860 Hz, and 3020 Hz, along with many other lower-magnitude frequency components.

Are the many other lower-magnitude frequency components infinite? Shouldn't they have been points on that line?

What are these: ${...,...,0,0,0,100,0,0,0,...,...}$? The frequency or sound pressure level? I don't see a 10 there for 10Hz so I am a bit confused.

Plotting softwares connect data points. In the first case, the data points are {x,y}, with x being the frequency axis and y the SPL. The data points connected are therefore {0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}, ... {10,100}, {11,0}, .... That's assuming a frequency axis where each x-axis value represents a 1Hz bin.
As for your first comment: there are points on that line. The plotting software connected them all through this "continuous-looking" line, because there are many data points.

I think you might need to take an introductory class on numeric softwares such as Matlab.  This has nothing to do with signal processing.

I have used Matlab before and have used matplotlib but in either case, you can create scatterplots.

that's correct! but also line plots, which is clearly what the authors are using there. Did my answer make sense in light of all this?
